# Ask user to save before closing then exit the winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

My below code should ask the user before closing the form, if no then exit the application itself.

```
private void DataEntry_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            String msg = "Confirm Save?";
            String caption = "Save Record";
            MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
            MessageBoxIcon ico = MessageBoxIcon.Question;
            DialogResult result;
            result = MessageBox.Show(this, msg, caption, buttons, ico);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                this.Validate();
                this.tool_ManagementBindingSource.EndEdit();
                this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.pINQCDataSet);
                MessageBox.Show("The Record saved Successfully", "Save_Update",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
            else
            {
                Application.Exit(); 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Saving Failed:" + ex.Message.ToString(), "Save",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

But I am getting message box appeared twice even after clicking no , then the below error appears , please guide me how to solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You're error seems to be produced when you select Yes, seems related to UpdateAll. Are you sure you have data in your DataGrid and it is in Edit mode?

Comment: You should show what `UpdateAll()` is doing. It probably returns before the job is complete, so the Form closes in the meanwhile, disposing its Controls. -- Remove `Application.Exit();`: this is your starting Form, the application is already exiting when this Form is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Do not call Application.Exit();

Simply set the `Cancel` property to `true`.

Have a look at [MS-Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks) about FormClosing event.

Quoted from Docs: (Bolds are mine)

> **Remarks**
>
> The **FormClosing** event occurs as the form is being closed. When a form is closed, it is disposed, releasing all resources associated with the form. If you cancel this event, the form remains opened. **To cancel the closure of a form**, set the **Cancel** property of the **FormClosingEventArgs** passed to your event handler to true.

Comment: Hi @McNets setting e.cancel = True will avoid closing the form , but i need to exit the application which is the opposite of that , can you pls guide again?

Comment: Isn't it the main form?

Comment: Yes it is the main form but the user should be able exit from the application by closing this form itself.

Comment: If it is the main form, Cancel=true prevents from closing the application. If you set Cancel=false application will ends.

Comment: can you pls change the above code and show ..i tried change at else event but the error is same.